# Is the 'Reachability' score in Alexa's SEO audit important?

Tags: seo, alexa

Alexa's SEO audit shows more than 9,900 pages as "unreachable" on my site. According to their definition, that means it requires six or more clicks to reach the page.

Has anyone ever dealt with this before? Is this a critical issue? What are ways to improve the reachability of pages?

Comment: Ignore it. Just do a decent site and ignore anything Alexa says. Alexa is useless garbage.

Comment: "What are ways to improve the reachability of pages?" Don't require six or more clicks to get to those pages.

Comment: According to [this review of Alexa's SEO audit](http://www.seobook.com/alexa-site-audit-review), it doesn't rank pages as "unreachable".   Pages are either "easy to find" or "hard to find" depending on how many clicks away from the home page they are.

Answer (score 2):

There is **nothing** in Alexa's reports that is important.

It may be useful to compare websites in the same niche, country, etc.  But overall, you should definitely not be relying on Alexa for anything important, especially analytics.

Comment: I would agree with your assesment of Alexa toolbar rankings, but this appears to be paid service from Alexa that may actually have some value.

Answer (score 0):

> Alexa's SEO audit shows more than 9,900 pages as "unreachable" on my
>   site.

If you have page so big, dude, get away from Alexa. This is not critical issue and you don't need to improve the reachability.

I strongly advise you to ignore alexa.

On their site they are saying:

> Alexa's traffic estimates are based on data from our global traffic
>   panel, which is a sample of millions of Internet users using one of
>   over 25,000 different browser extensions.

I know it's big number, but srsly, ignore it completley.

Comment: What do you mean by "have page so big"?      I'm also not sure why you are quoting about Alexa's ranking for a question about their SEO audit service.

Comment: It states that those sites are unreachable. People who are using alexa have that kind of errors all the time, and I'm quoting this part from alexa just to tell him to ignore it. It's not about the numbers when we're talking about alexa. It's about not using alexa.

Comment: The question isn't about a site being unreachable.  It's about pages that are more than six clicks away from the home page in Alexa's SEO audit reachability report.

Comment: Yes. I know. That's why I wroted this: "This is not critical issue and you don't need to improve the reachability."

Answer (score 0):

Alexa's tool crawls your site and ranks each page by how many clicks it takes to get there. Any page that is many clicks away from the home page is going to be very hard to rank in search engines.  Pages that far from the home page are not going to inherit enough reputation from the rest of your site.  Search engines are going to view them as unimportant.

I can't speak for how well this tool from Alexa actually works, but pages that are difficult to navigate to in your site can be a severe SEO problem.

If the "hard to find" pages are pages that you would like to have ranking, you should link to them more often and from more prominent places. If these pages are:

- Product pages
- Articles
- Bringing in search engine traffic

It would be worth it to link them better.  On the other hand if these pages are:

- Out of date
- Products not in stock
- Low quality

Then they are probably fine as is.   You might even want to take action to prevent them from being crawled or indexed altogether.  Consider blocking them in *robots.txt* or adding `noindex` to them.